# How can I echo square brackets in php

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, square-bracket

I want to echo the following code, but its not working:

```
<?php
if ( is_page('residenz') ) 
{ echo '[nggallery id=12]'; } 
else if ( is_page('apartment-royal-ii') ) 
{ echo '[nggallery id=13]'; } 
else if ( is_page('apartment-royal-iii') ) 
{ echo '[nggallery id=14]'; } 
else if ( is_page('apartment-royal-iv') ) 
{ echo '[nggallery id=15]'; } 
else if ( is_page('apartment-royal-v') ) 
{ echo '[nggallery id=16]'; } 
else { echo '[nggallery id=11]'; } 
?>
```

I assume that the problem is in the square brackets.

How can I echo [nggallery id=11] for instance?

Some more info:

The code is executed in a wordpress widget.

This is how I modified the widgets to accept php:

```
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
function execute_php($html){
     if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
          ob_start();
          eval("?".">".$html);
          $html=ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
     }
     return $html;
}
```

EDIT2:

I used this and it works:

```
<?php
if (1 == 1)
{?>
 [nggallery id=13]
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Try escaping the character.

Comment: So what exactly is being displayed?

Comment: Echoing brackets [works fine](http://codepad.org/ESyxv8dH) for me.  What's not working about your code?

Comment: the example you gave doesnt work for me. I have modified wodpress widgets to accept php code. echo "abc" works but with square brackets nothing gets displayed from the whole widget.

Comment: @user1721135 Try Shahzab's answer below, it worked for me.

Comment: I found a fix, thx for your comments.

Comment: @user1721135 Great, what was your fix?

Comment: not using the brackets within php tag see my last edit

Comment: @user1721135 Right on, glad it worked out, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code for echo the data:

```
<?php
echo htmlentities('[nggallery id=12]');
?>
```

Comment: Works beautifully ;-)

Comment: You really should be using the WordPress do_shortcode function rather than just an echo here... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets do not need to be escaped. I think that your conditions evaluate to false. 
See what is the output of the following statement:

```
var_dump(is_page['residenz'])
```

Comment: I dont get any output, even without any condition it brakes. Basically the whole widget displays nothing, not even whats outside the php tags

Comment: Please edit your question and include information about which platform you are using + the corresponding tag...

Comment: edited with what I have in my functions.php, how I modified wordpress